# Accompanist webview prevents other composables from showing

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have the following screen which should show a loading indicator while the website isn't shown. However the `WebView` prevents any other composables from showing up until it is ready to show the website.

How can I show something else on this screen before the website shows up?

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material3.LinearProgressIndicator
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.google.accompanist.web.LoadingState
import com.google.accompanist.web.WebView
import com.google.accompanist.web.rememberWebViewState

@Composable
fun UrlScreen() {
    val state = rememberWebViewState(url = "https://stackoverflow.com")
    Column {
        val loadingState = state.loadingState
        if (loadingState is LoadingState.Loading) {
            LinearProgressIndicator(
                progress = loadingState.progress,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
        Text("This text won't show up before the website shows up.")
        WebView(
            state = state,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm finding this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but I noticed that if you have it in a scaffold with a FAB then the FAB is shown.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue while I was implementing my own WebView wrapper based on Accompanist WebView component. I had flag `android:hardwareAccelerated="true` in the manifest for the WebWiew's hosted activity. In my case adding `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` for the CustomWebView component fixed the issue.

Here is snipped of my code:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        CustomWebView(context).apply {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
           }
   })
```

Maybe it will help or direct you to the solution.

Comment: Yes adding "setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)" solves the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to set `clipToOutline = true` on the webview as recommended by the [documentation on `AndroidView`](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/42d844f7f349384761bca5dad6adaed43a8ae677/compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/AndroidView.android.kt#L175) and [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174233728#comment5) on the google issue tracker.

```kotlin
WebView(context).apply {
    clipToOutline = true
}
```